# Waiting for text input in crafty

Tags: javascript, html, time, craftyjs

I am making a game in the style of old final fantasy games with a maths test twist, so whenever the user attempts an action in combat he has to answer a question. the problem is that I cant get the program to stop until they have done an input (So currently they can get a question right then just keep doing actions with that answer, or before even putting an answer in atall). I tried making an infinite loop until text input was used but this did not work as it stopped text input aswell, here are the componenets that control combat and define the textbox (which is a html forms text box):

```
//component to take text input for questions and mabye other stuff
Crafty.c('InputText', {
init:function() {
this.requires('Actor')
Crafty.e("HTML")
.attr({x:550, y:200, w:100, h:100})
.append("<form name='Textinput'><div id='Text'>Answer: </div><input type='text'   name='GuessAnswer' id='GuessAnswer'><input type='button' value='Go' onclick='SaveText()'></form>");
},
});

//player character during combat
//This also controls player input during combat and resolves most of the combat
//Will display and take inputs for quesions eventually
Crafty.c('BattlePlayer', {
init:function() {
var OpPos = 1;
var HealthPas = 100 + ',' + 100;
FightOver = false;
monsterBeat = false;
//Displays options for the first time with attack selected
this.requires('Actor, spr_BattlePlayer, SpriteAnimation, Keyboard')
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('SPACE')) Crafty.scene('World');})
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('ENTER')) HealthPas =  this.BattleSelect(OpPos, HealthPas);})
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('S')) if (OpPos < 3){OpPos = OpPos +  1}; this.MenuMove(OpPos); })
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('W')) if (OpPos > 1) {OpPos = OpPos - 1}; this.MenuMove(OpPos); });

Crafty.e('InputText');
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 100, y: 80 })
.text('Enemy:')
.textColor('#C8C8C8');
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 100, y: 130 })
.text('Player:')
.textColor('#C8C8C8');
Crafty.audio.stop('Footstep');
Crafty.e('HealthBar').at(1,4);
Crafty.e('HealthBar').at(1,6);
this.HealthDisplay(HealthPas);

Crafty.e('AttackSel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('HealUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);

var MenuPos = 1;    

},
//function for displaying what option is currently selected
MenuMove: function(OpPos) {
switch (OpPos)
{
case 1:
//Attack case
Crafty.e('AttackSel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('HealUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);
break;

case 2:
//Defend case
Crafty.e('AttackUnsel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('HealSel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);
break;

case 3:
//Run case
Crafty.e('AttackUnsel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('HealUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunSel').at(3,18);
break;

default:
//Incorrect input case
Crafty.e('AttackUnsel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('HealUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);
}
},

HealthDisplay: function(HealthPas) {
var Nums = HealthPas.split(',');
for (var i = 1; i<(Nums[1]/10)+1; i++)
{
    Crafty.e('HealthBlock').at(i,4);
}
for (var i = 1; i<(Nums[0]/10)+1; i++)
{
    Crafty.e('HealthBlock').at(i,6);
}
},

//function to pause game untill answer has been made
AnswerPause: function() {
MadeGuess = false;
while (MadeGuess == false)
{

}
},

//function for carrying out battle options
//Within this function Num[0] represents players health and Nums[1] represents the Enemy Health.
BattleSelect: function(OpPos, HealthPas) {
var Nums = HealthPas.split(',');
//this.AnswerPause();
switch (OpPos)
{
case 1:
//Attack case
//if the fight has been resolved, no further combat actions can be taken
if (FightOver == false)
{
if (AnsCorrect == true)
{
//takes away enemy health
Nums[1] = Nums[1] - 20;
Crafty.audio.play('attack');
}
this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1]);
//takes away player health
Nums[0] = Nums[0] - 10; 
}
break;

case 2:
//Heal case
//as this was originaly a string, minus 1 to change it to an integer
Nums[0] = Nums[0] - 1 + 21;
if (Nums[0] > 100)
{
Nums[0] = 100;
}
this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1]);
break;

case 3:
//Run case
//switch checks what room the player is in the transport them back there
this.LocationFind();
break;

default:
this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1]);
Nums[0] = Nums[0] - 10;
}

this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1]);
//put player and monster health values back to allow both to be passed back to componenet.
HealthPas = Nums[0] + ',' + Nums[1];
//Displays Player and Enemy Health via a 10 part health bar
if (OpPos != 3)
{   
Crafty.e('HealthBar').at(1,4);
Crafty.e('HealthBar').at(1,6);
this.HealthDisplay(HealthPas);
}
return HealthPas;
},

//
//function to check for winning conditions
EndCheck : function(PlayerHealth, EnemyHealth)
{
if (EnemyHealth < 1)
    {
    FightOver = true;
    monsterBeat = true;
    }
else if (PlayerHealth < 1)
    {
    FightOver = true;
    }

if (monsterBeat == true)
{   
this.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('ENTER')) this.LocationFind();})
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 500, y: 150 })
.text('Victory!');
}   
else if (FightOver == true)
{
this.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('ENTER')) this.LocationFind();})
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 500, y: 150 })
.text('Defeat!');
}
},

});
```

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle which shows the problem? I would be glad to look at it then, i can't read the whole code and understand it sadly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would be the best approach, but you could simply pause crafty's game loop until they finished:

`Crafty.pause(true)`

And then unpause it once you received the input:

`Crafty.pause(false)`

This will stop things like background animations, though.  Also, I'm not sure it'll disable the dispatch of keyboard/mouse events, which might be important.

A more flexible approach might be to have components you cared about listen for a pause event; that lets you pick and choose how components behave, but you'd have to implement this yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever that 'Go' button is clicked, it is calling a function named 'SaveText()'. SaveText could be implemented to do what you need, or it could easily call a different function like 'ContinueBattle()'.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP is asking for help with -- how to implement it.

Comment: Ok, I guess I didn't understand the question, then. I thought that was an answer. Replace 'SaveText()' with whatever code you want to run. There's the event handler that the OP asked for.

Comment: OP states quite clearly: "the problem is that I cant get the program to stop until they have done an input".    The problem is not getting the input, it is pausing the game loop.

Comment: Alright. In that case, please tell OP that I am sorry that I wasted everybody's time and that I couldn't be more help. Sorry for any trouble that I caused and I won't bother you again.

Comment: Huh, you seem to be taking this personally?  I'm not trying to pick on you --  it's generally considered to be polite to leave a note when you downvote an answer, explaining why.

Comment: Just to clarify here, I guess I meant that maybe he didn't need to actually stop everything, rather wait until that `ContinueBattle()` call to act as a notification for things to be allowed to happen.